# Halftone dotted shape with rotation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, halftone, rotate

I am trying to make a rotated dotted shape like in the picture. I already succeeded creating the dotted pattern using the blend tool or make a halftone pattern. I am stuck now with the rotation in the middle.
My idea was to use ‚envelope distort‘ but I still don’t get the same result. With me it looks weird.
I would appreciate any help or hint.

[image: Halftone dotted shape]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method, but it's quite manual. What follows is quite a rough example, with a brief outline of how you could do it. Obviously you could spend much more time on it for a better result.

1. Create a step blend to approximate one line of ellipses. Something like this

[image]

[image]

2. Turn this into an Art Brush
3. Using your example as a guide, draw some lines of equal length like this

[image]

4. Apply the Art Brush to the lines, and use the Width Tool to vary the width of each line.

[image]

While this works, kind of, it might be better to consider using actual 3D software for something like this. Blender (which is free) is capable of doing this - [see example](https://imgur.com/b5jup04)

Comment: Thank you very much. That looks good already. I will try it.

Answer (score 2):

Envelope distortion makes at least something resembling if the undistorted original and the envelope are guessed right. In the next image the upper shape is my guess of the original and the lower is the same after applying envelope distortion with 1x1 mesh and tweaking the corners a while:

[image]

It may be tricky to make the undistorted original pattern in Illustrator. It's imported from Inkscape where tiling circles with scaling to both directions is elementary. Inkscape can use the brighness or RGB numbers of an underlying image for the scaling - a perfect vector halftoning! Here a black to light grey radial gradient was used.

As a 3D object it looks like the original pattern is mapped on a rectangle which has got a linear 90 degrees twist. Unfortunately I do not have a 3D program which does it so that the mapped (and twisted) pattern can be extracted as a 2D vector and one could see the backside too. Here's a low resolution rendering attempt, but it's a bitmap only and the rectangle cannot be made transparent.

[image]

It really is perfectly 3D because it's made in a 3D program, but is it close enough the shape you expected is not clear. At least it cannot be reused, because it's a low resolution bitmap. Something advanced is needed, maybe Blender, but that's said already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. That really seams more difficult than I first thaught. I succeed with distortion but, as you said, it doesn't get the 3D look. I will probably try with Blender.